# Spotted and yellow avocado leaves

Tags: avocado

Grown this avocado from seed, indoors, for three years. Recently, the leaves have been displaying a weird speckled pattern, then turning dramatically yellow very quickly and falling off. No evidence of mites but really not sure how to account for this sudden change and the damage it’s doing. [image][image]